# What would be the solution for this question if it had strong test cases?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, primes

```
https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIME1
```

If you don't wish to open the link here's a short description of the question below :

This problem asks us to print all prime number within a given range.
There are 10 test cases and each one will provide us a start and end value of a range.
The start and end of this range can take values between 1 and 10^9.
The difference between the start and end values is 10^5 or lesser.
The time limit for the problem is 2 seconds. (that is, for all 10 test cases together)

My thinking on this:

A common estimate is that the online judge used by Codechef can perform ~10^7 operations in 1 second.
We have 10 test cases and in the worst case each one will have a range of 10^5 (since that's the max range given). Now, 
10*(10^5)= 10^6 , which is the max number of operations we can perform in 1 second,  so for each number in the range we must identify if it is prime in O(1).

```
Approaches:

1. Simple method for testing primality - Iterate through all numbers from 2 to n-1 and for every number check if it divides n
Ans: Won't work because for the worst case,
= (numbers of the highest size) * (total numbers in max range) * (total test cases)
= (10^9 * 10^5) * 10
= 10^15

2. Square root method to check if prime
Ans: Won't work because, in the worst case,
= (calculating sq. root of numbers of size 10^9) * (total numbers in max range) * (total test cases)
= (~10^4) * (10^5) * 10
= 10^10

3. Using Sieve of Eratosthenes
Precompute primes from 1 to 32000 (this number because it is approx the sq. root of 10^9)
Then to check of a value within the range is primeor not-
if value is between 1 and 32000
    directly refer the precomputed value
else
    try dividing that value by all precomputed primes, if it divides evenly then its not a prime
Ans: won't work  because, in the worst case,
= (number of primes between 1 and 32000) *(total numbers in max range) * (total test cases)
= (3234) * (10^5)  * (10)
= 10^9
```

Code for approach 3:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    static ArrayList<Integer> sieve(ArrayList<Integer> primes)
    {
        int[] prime=new int[32001];
        for(int i=2; i<32001; i++)
        {
            if(prime[i]==0)
            {
                for(int j=i+i; j<32001; j+=i)
                {
                    prime[j]=1;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=2; i<32001; i++)
        {
            if(prime[i]==0)
            {
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }

        return primes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int t,m,n,flag;
        ArrayList<Integer> primes= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        FastReader scanner= new FastReader();
        t=scanner.nextInt();
        primes= sieve(primes);
        while(t-- > 0)
        {
            m=scanner.nextInt();
            n=scanner.nextInt();

            for(int i=m; i<=n; i++)
            {
                if(i < 32001)
                {
                    if(primes.contains(i))
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    flag=0;
                    for(int j=0; j<primes.size(); j++)
                    {
                        if(i%primes.get(j) == 0)
                        {
                            flag=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(flag==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

While approach 1 obviously didn't work, approach 2 and 3 surprisingly passed!
I'm guessing it passed because the test cases for the problem were weak.
A strong test case would be something like:

```
10
999900000 1000000000
999899999 999999999
999899998 999999998
999899997 999999997
999899996 999999996
999899995 999999995
999899994 999999994
999899993 999999993
999899992 999999992
999899991 999999991
```

I ran approach 3 for this test case and it is always taking more than 2 seconds to compute.
If this question did have strong test cases, what would be the correct approach to solve it with the given constraints?

Comment: You can sieve in the given range using the small primes.

Comment: Use a [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) to store if a number is not a prime..

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Your operations calculations don't take into account that for any sizable range, the majority of numbers are ruled out very quickly (eg over 60% of the numbers are divisible by 2 or 3 alone).  Precomputing the primes is the way to go - but not using that sieve implementation !  That's OK for a demo or exercise, but use more efficient prime-finding when using for real.

Answer (score 1):

If you going to try figure out prime numbers in a range use the Sieve of Eratosthene algorithm. The basic premise of Sieve is that give a range of numbers you eliminate all numbers that are multiples of prime factors (i.e once we establish that 2 is prime, we eliminate all its multiples ...4, 6, 8, etc)

A implementation of this would be as follows:

```
private void printPrimes(int max) {
   int [] prime = new int[max + 1];
   for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
       prime[i] = i; // Assume everything is prime initially
   }

   // if number is prime, then  multiples of that factor are not prime
   for (int f = 2; f * f <= max; f++) {
       if (prime[f] != 0) {
           for (int j = f; f * j <= max; j++) {
               prime[f * j] = 0;
           }
       }
   }

   int counter = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
       if (prime[i] != 0) counter++;
   }

   prime = Arrays.stream(prime).filter(i -> i != 0).toArray();
   System.out.println("There are " + counter + " primes between 1 and " + max);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(prime));
}
```

Comment: This code will fail for checking if 121 is prime or not....this code will only work for small numbers...….according to the constraints I can get a number as large as 10^8....

Comment: If you actually tried running the code, you'll see it'll work fine for establishing if 121 is prime or not. Yes, for 10^8 the array will throw you a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error, but that is due to the limitations of the Collection. So if you put in a mechanism to flush the Collection ever so often,it'll work just fine.I added `if(primes.size() >= 100000) { System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primes.toArray())); primes.clear(); }` and it ran through 1 to 10^8 in about 44s (bear in mind that `System.out.println` takes up a good chuck of that processing time).

Comment: I ran your code with min=120 and max=130 and it gave this output- [121, 127]……Isn't 121 non-prime...?

Comment: If I add 11 it'll work for 121 but now won't work for 169.... this will go on....Also the constraints give us only 2 seconds of runtime....

Comment: Updated the implementation to reflect Sieves a better, it also ran within the constraint give for 1 to 10^8. You'll just need to figure out if you want to start from a min that is not 1.

Comment: You can save space in two ways.  First use a BitSet for your sieve, not an array.  You only need a single bit to flag prime or composite.  Second, all even numbers except 2 are composite.  Your sieve only needs to hold one bit for every odd number in the range, together with a little extra code to deal with 2 if it is in the range.

Comment: @Vinayak, did this solve your problem? If it did, please check the empty check mark on the left. Tx.